# JPA - Select, Join, Subquery and max

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I try to map this query into JPA and Join, Subqueries and other are to much for me. Maybe you can help me. this is my query:

```sql
SELECT customers.*
FROM actions
         JOIN customers
              ON customers.id = actions.customer_id
WHERE actions.action_type = 'CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN'
  AND actions.created IN (
    SELECT max(created)
    FROM actions
    WHERE action_type = 'CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN'
       OR action_type = 'CUSTOMER_TRAINING_END'
    GROUP BY customer_id
);
```

I try to collect all Customers, where the last Status (CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN or CUSTOMER_TRAINING_END) was CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN. There are other Status, but i only want those 2.

So I have these Tables:

```
                     Table "public.actions"  
   Column    |           Type           |       Modifiers           
-------------+--------------------------+------------------------   
 id          | bigint                   | not null   
 action_type | character varying(30)    | not null   
 user_name   | character varying(30)    | not null   
 customer_id | bigint                   |    
 created     | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()   
 updated     | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()   

                     Table "public.customers"
    Column    |           Type           |       Modifiers        
--------------+--------------------------+------------------------
 id           | integer                  | not null
 fore_name    | character varying(50)    | not null
 last_name    | character varying(50)    | not null
 matrikel     | integer                  | not null
 day_of_birth | timestamp with time zone | not null
 created      | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 updated      | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
```

And my code snippets:

Customer.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Customer extends AbstractTimestampEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CUSTOMERS_ID_SEQ", name = "CUSTOMERS_ID_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CUSTOMERS_ID_GEN", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "FORE_NAME")
    private String foreName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "MATRIKEL")
    private int matrikelNumber;

    @Column(name = "DAY_OF_BIRTH")
    private Date dayOfBirth;

}
```

ActionType.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum ActionType {
    /**
     * Customer starts training.
     */
    CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN("ActionType.customerTrainingBegin.label"),
    /**
     * Customer stops training
     */
    CUSTOMER_TRAINING_END("ActionType.customerTrainingEnd.label");

    @Getter
    private String labelKey;
}
```

Action.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIONS")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Action extends AbstractTimestampEntity {
  
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ACTIONS_ID_SEQ", name = "actions_id_gen", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "actions_id_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_NAME")
    private User user;
 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Customer customer;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ACTION_TYPE")
    private ActionType type;

}
```

My Problem is, that i hav to collect Customers. I have to join from Action to Customer because i don't have a refrence from customer to action. So i can't do something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Customer> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> from = query.from(Customer.class);

query.select(from);

// Join here to action...
```

Maybe this helps to understand my problem. Thanks a lot.

Greetings, Chesmuh

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your entities/mappings. Without knowing things like the relationship between `Customer` and `ActionCustomer` (e.g. is `ActionCustomer` a subclass of `Customer`?), this is hard to answer.

Comment: Sorry, miss those damn small comments every time ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

You need to map also the `created` column of `actions` table. Then you can apply the following JPQL query (please note the changes in the subselect; the way you designed your SQL query, it wouldn't have brought the results you wanted):

```
SELECT a.customer
FROM Action a
WHERE a.type = 'CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN' 
AND a.created = 
(
SELECT max(created)
FROM Action
WHERE (type = 'CUSTOMER_TRAINING_BEGIN' 
OR type = 'CUSTOMER_TRAINING_END')
AND customer.id = a.customer.id
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i switch a.customer with a.customer_id its the same result as my query. But i try to write these Query in JPA with the Criteria Builder.

Comment: May I ask why do you prefer criteria instead of JPQL? :)